# Difference in load test results

Tags: performance, jmeter, load, loadrunner

What can be the reason for difference in results of load test run at different times with SAME bandwidth?
If I run load test at midnight the response times would be better and during they are real bad. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there traffic when results are bad?

Comment: But I have enough bandwidth available, still traffic matter?

Comment: Changes in initial and in-test conditions.    At midnight you have less contention on a shared component, likely the network.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe during the day the application is being used by real users and your artificial load is being added to the natural load?

Another option is that network is more busy during the day so channel bandwidth is fully utilized.

Load testing tool itself metrics don't tell the full story, you can only make assumptions by looking at [TCP connect](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/know-how/introduction-to-tcp/) time metric.

If you have an [APM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) system in place you can assess what's going on with the system during the daytime and night time and detect the factors which are impacting the response time. If you don't - you can set up your own by using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)

Comment: I run test only in Performance test environment.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Dmitri's note, there could be multiple reasons / causes for difference in results.

1. As Dmitri pointed check your APM tool to see server health while tests is executing
2. Do you integrate with any downstream applications? Do these applications reside in a stable and dedicated perf testing environment or they are live production environments? if it is later, then you should expect a latency in response during day time
3. Authentication / token validation - usually gateways are configured to validate incoming bearer token. when you execute during morning time there is a possibility that your gateway could be busy serving other real users requests (assuming this a production AD / Okta / PingID servers)